# How would I move all the elements in a list left or right in Python?

Tags: python, list

I would like to make a program that will take a list:

```
myList = [a,b,c]
```

and be able to move all elements left or right, and drop anything that would be pushed out, replacing everything else with a 0:

```
moveRight(mylist) = [0,a,b]
moveLeft(myList) = [b,c,0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could slice the list to remove the relevant elements and add `[0]` to it:

```
def moveRight(mylist):
    return ['0'] + myList[:-1]

def moveLeft(mylist):
    return myList[1:] + ['0']
```

Answer (score 3):

Slicing is very helpful:

```
def moveRight(mylist, distance=1, pad=0):
    return ([pad] * distance) + mylist[:0 - distance]

def moveLeft(mylist, distance=1, pad=0):
    return mylist[distance:] + ([pad] * distance)
```

You could also do the change in-place:

```
def moveRight(mylist, distance=1, pad=0):
    mylist[:] = ([pad] * distance) + mylist[:0 - distance]

def moveLeft(mylist, distance=1, pad=0):
    mylist[:] = mylist[distance:] + ([pad] * distance)
```

Both ways, the default is to shift by one, but you could shift by any positive integer.  You can also use something other than `0` to fill in the missing elements with.

Comment: Maybe these functions could have a `pad_value=0` argument to make them even more generic.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Excellent suggestion.  I have now implemented it.

Comment: Great - but looks like you forgot to add the argument on all the functions in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the size of the collection to be preserved, use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) from the collections module

```
from collections import deque

>>> d = deque(list(range(1, 6)), maxlen=5)
>>> d.append(0)
>>> d
deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 0], maxlen=5)
>>> d.appendleft(0)
>>> d
deque([0, 2, 3, 4, 5], maxlen=5)
```

deque also has extend and extendleft methods to add multiple elements at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make good use of [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) from `collections` module in your case:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> 
>>> q = deque(maxlen=3)
>>>
>>> q.extend(['a','b','c'])
>>> 
>>> q
deque(['a', 'b', 'c'], maxlen=3)
>>> q.appendleft(0)
>>> q
deque([0, 'a', 'b'], maxlen=3)
>>> q.append(0)
>>> q
deque(['a', 'b', 0], maxlen=3)
```

The idea here is to keep the `queue` of fixed size so whenever you append an item from either right or left the item on the opposite end gets pushed out.

Quoting from [*Python Cookbook 3rd Edition*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027072.do) :

> Adding or popping items from either end of a queue has O(1)
>   complexity. This is unlike a list where inserting or removing items
>   from the front of the list is O(N).